# How to Repeat Image to Fill Background in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i Got a Small Tile Image. i Want to set The Background with that image and I want to Repeat the Image to Fill the Entire background. For Example in CSS we Repeat the Background image with repeat-x and repeat-y property.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the with and height of image to calculate how many times you should repeat the image.
It's not difficult but luckily there is already a module on Code Exchange.
You can use that and modify it for your needs if required.
http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/tilebg-tile-and-manage-image-display-background

See Code Exchange for more libraries: http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/